# Implement service with play framework in which one parameter is a url

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework

I am creating a web service with play framework and scala. The service get a url and a language, and use this information, but i can't put a url into the service.

I have this in routes
    GET     /trans/$url<(http%3A%2F%2Fa)>/:lang                 controllers.Application.getTranslation(url:String, lang:String)

and in Application:
    def getTranslation(iri: String,lang:String) = Action { implicit request => 
etc.

and i want to receive something like 
    **'/trans/htp://a/es'** (its http instead of htp but i can't write it here)

is it posible? Because i've tried everything and i'm not able. is ther ane way to pass a url as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You have to url escape and unescape on both sides. It is called URL Encoding or Percent Encoding (because escaped character are rewritten using a combination that start with %)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Here is a question that give you information if your client side is in js:
[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

And here is nice scala library that can be used to encode and decode URL persent encoding.
https://github.com/theon/scala-uri

I have started scala myself (most of my prod work on playframework is still in Java), so I do not know if there is a better scala uri library out there.

EDIT :
You got me curious so I searched a bit:
http://www.motobit.com/util/url-encoder.asp
you should be carefull about the encoding on both sides.

Comment: Ok thank you, with this i can decode and encode the URL, but i still have a problem. In the routes file, how can i pass a url like:  http://localhost:9000/trans/'http://hello.com'/es   I have the routes definited:                                         GET     /trans/:iri/:lang        controllers.Application.getTranslation(url:String, lang:String)      But it only works if y pass the url with encoding %...

Comment: well the string you will receive as the url param of your getTranslation(url, lang) will be escaped, then you have to unescape it within the function before using it. I am not entirely what is your issue here? Maybe do an edit of your question with a bit of code example and your use  case? That would help me ... help you?